# Create JSON Request string using Javascript Overlay types in GWT

Tags: json, gwt

We have used JSO for our JSON parsing in GWT client side. Now, we need to convert our Java objects to JSON string. I just wanted to understand, how we can achieve this? JSO overlay types was used for JSON parsing. Can it also be used to create a JSON request string or do we have to go by some other means?

Comment: Thanks Stefan...I have done that now. I was new to stackoverflow and hence was not aware that I need to go and say Accept answer. Thanks again..Hope somebody replies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generating a JSON object in JavaScript is pretty simple. You can do it like this:

```
var obj = { "var1": "hello", "var2": "world" };
```

this will generate a JSON object with two varibles ("var1" and "var2") with their values ("hello", "world").
The Object can be converted into a String (for sending purposes) with the `JSON.stringify(jso);` method.

Generating JSON data from the java code isn't possible (well not with a usefull result) since all varibles are optimzed to single Strings, so applying this method wouldn't hava a usefull result (if even possible).

If you have already a JSO object (generated with something like safeeval). You can edit your varibles there, like this:

```
public final native void newValue(String newValue) /*-{
    this.ValueName = newValue;
}-*/;
```

If you then want the object as string you have to define the following method in your JSO class:

```
    public final native String returnAsString () /*-{
    return JSON.stringify(this);
}-*/;
```

or use this in you Java class: `String s = (new JSONObject(jso)).toString();`.

This way you can edit your original intput data and send the original object back to the server.

BR

Comment: Thanks...Okey. So editing an existing JSO and returning back to server with string is fine. But, if I have a java object, then we have to manually create the json string is it? I mean, we do not have any option to create a JSO from java object and then use JSO feature to create a json..

Comment: already wrote what I think about this:
Generating JSON data from the java code isn't possible (well not with a usefull result) since all varibles are optimzed to single Strings, so applying this method wouldn't hava a usefull result (if even possible).